# finding max using template

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to C++ template and learning from [C++ Templates The Complete Guide](http://www.amazon.in/Templates-Complete-Guide-David-Vandevoorde/dp/0201734842).
In second chapter there is function find maximum value from argument. Please have look at below code.

```
#include <iostream>

#define PRINT(x) std::cout<<#x<<":"<<x<<std::endl;
template <typename T>
inline T const& max(T const& a,T const& b)
{
    return a>b?a:b;
}
int main(){
    int a=4;
    PRINT(a);
    PRINT(&a);
    double b=3.1;
    PRINT(b);
    PRINT(&b);
    double const & c = ::max<double>(a,b);
    PRINT(c);
    PRINT(&c);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output.**

> a:4 &a:0x7ffe1522731c
>
> b:3.1 &b:0x7ffe15227320
>
> c:4 &c:0x7ffe15227328

I didn't understand,why address `&a` and `&c` are not same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not specific to templates, and the same happens without them.

The root cause is that C++ references are not smart pointers. They do not automatically manage memory.

Specifically, what happens here is that you pass `int a=4` to `max<double>(double const& a, double const& b)`. Since there's a type mismatch, and `max` promises not to change the values anyway (const reference), C++ generates a **temporary** double with value `4.0`. This temporary lives to the *end of the full expression*, in other words until the semicolon at the end of that line.

That's unfortunate. That line is the initialization of `double const& c`. So c is initialized as a reference to a temporary `4.0`, and the temporary goes away **immediately** after that initialization!

You now have a reference to an ex-double. It's no more. It's pining for the fjords.

In particular, trying to use `c` on the next line is Undefined Behavior, and anything can happen. The proper fix would be to have `max<double>` return a `double`. This is another value. And since `4.0 > 3.1`, you get back the **value** `4.0`. The reference `const double& c` now binds to another temporary initialized with that value `4.0`.

Rule: binding a temporary to a `const&` extends the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of that `const&`, **and only that particular reference**. Initializing a second reference with the first reference doesn't work like a smart pointer, and won't extend the lifetime of the temporary.

Answer (score 1):

How *could* it be the same? With `max<double>` you say that the template type `T` is a `double`, meaning it returns a reference to a `double`. But `a` is an `int` which gets converted to a `double`.

The reference that `max<double>` returns is a reference to the temporary value created to store the converted value of `a`.

That it work at all is because you have references to `const`, which prolongs the lifetime of temporary values.

Answer (score 0):

You have `a` defined as `int`,

```
int a=4;
```

but returned from `max` function as `double`. It is on different adress, and result can be potentially unexpected behaviour.

Comment: "returned from max function as `double`." You might want to check that, its returned as `double const&`. And that is critically relevant. The problem is not just unexpected behavior, it's Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Because

```
 double const & c =
```

tells the compiler to allocate enough memory to fit a double const&, which is then immediatly occupied by assigning the value of max. This is a definition, not a declaration.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not what happens. There is (most likekly) no allocation, and no assignment. You are also mixing types `double const&` is not `double`, so it cannot hold value of `max`. It can hold a reference to value returned by max. The conversion happens on passing `a` as the parameter, not upon returning the result.